# Select persons who do only the project with the same city

Tags: t-sql

So I have 3 tables: Management (…, personID, projectID //personID and projectID can dublicate)  Project(id, city, …) and Person (id, name, city, …)
I need to output persons who **only** do projects with the same city. 
Will be greatfull for any help or idea.

Comment: Please be more specific. Is this question about SQL?

Comment: Yes, I thought 'tsql' is enough to mention.

Comment: Sorry, missed the tag - always a good idea to repeat the context inside your question. That said, it’s not a very precise question. Is a single person working alone on a project in a city part of the result or do you want only persons (plural) in the result. How about projects without someone working on them? I think you need to rephrase it more exactly.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. So almost everything is in main table Management, we put there ProjectID and PersonID  (not nulls, not unique) and other details,  so every project has a person, often 1, and every person can have a lot of projects. In equal tables Project and Person there is only name and city, this tables are very simple. Main target, is to output that personsID, who has  only project in the same city inside Person table (on Management.personsID = personsID)  as city in Project table (every project has also one city). **Sorry for my bad English(

Comment: I get your relations. But it’s unclear if you search for one specific project or if you want a list of all projects. Also unclear is how you want your result. Are you looking for just one sql query which would return many rows or do you want some code that processes the persons for each projects and city.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @Yevgny please post queries to create the tables and to insert some sample data instead of trying to describe the the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple query with joins, group by, having, and count(distinct) that gets the desired results.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @Project as table
(
    id int,
    city varchar(20)
);

DECLARE @Person as table
(
    id int,
    firstName varchar(10),
    lastName varchar(10)
);

DECLARE @Managment as table
(
    projectId int,
    personId int
);

INSERT INTO @Project (id, city) VALUES
(1, 'Abilene'),
(2, 'Akron'),
(3, 'Albuquerque'),
(4, 'Alexandria'),
(5, 'Allentown');

INSERT INTO @Person (Id, firstName, lastName) VALUES
(1, 'Aaron', 'Carter'),
(2, 'Aaron', 'Eckhart'),
(3, 'Abbie', 'Cornish'),
(4, 'Ace', 'Young'),
(5, 'Adam', 'Brody');

INSERT INTO @Managment (projectId, personId) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(3, 3),
(3, 2),
(3, 5),
(4, 4),
(4, 1),
(5, 5);
```

The query:

```
SELECT personId, firstName, lastName, max(city) as city
FROM @Person As pe
JOIN @Managment As m
    ON pe.Id = m.personId
JOIN @Project As pr
    ON pr.Id = m.projectId
GROUP BY personId, firstName, lastName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT city) = 1
```

(I've added the city's name as a bonus if you wanted two cities you could go with `max` and `min`, more than that you can't) - note the usage of `count(distinct city)` in the `having` clause.

Results:

```
personId    firstName   lastName    city
3           Abbie       Cornish     Albuquerque
4           Ace         Young       Alexandria
```